# cannot .bind context on arrow function in object method

Tags: javascript, class, this

So, I have a school example, but with `createCardPicker: () => {}` like arrow function method, it does not work and does not see the context. Why?

P.S.
I did not need to rewrite my object in any other presentation, just to brings it work as is. Thanks.

```
let deck = {
    suits: ["hearts", "spades", "clubs", "diamonds"],
    cards: Array(52),
    createCardPicker: () => {
        return () => {
            let pickedCard = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52);
            let pickedSuit = Math.floor(pickedCard / 13);

            return alert(this.suits[pickedSuit], pickedCard % 13)
        }
    }
}

deck.createCardPicker.bind(deck)()(); //undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way the arrow function works. It "passes" `this` one level up.

This will work as you expect:

```js
let deck = {
    suits: ["hearts", "spades", "clubs", "diamonds"],
    cards: Array(52),
    createCardPicker: function() {
        return () => {
            let pickedCard = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52);
            let pickedSuit = Math.floor(pickedCard / 13);

            return `${this.suits[pickedSuit]} ${pickedCard % 13}`
        }
    }
}

console.log(deck.createCardPicker.bind(deck)()()); //undefined
```

However you dont have to even bind it

```js
let deck = {
    suits: ["hearts", "spades", "clubs", "diamonds"],
    cards: Array(52),
    createCardPicker: function() {
        return () => {
            let pickedCard = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52);
            let pickedSuit = Math.floor(pickedCard / 13);

            return `${this.suits[pickedSuit]} ${pickedCard % 13}`
        }
    }
}

console.log(deck.createCardPicker()()); //undefined
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, I know how to bring it work throw ES5 function inside the method, like `createCardPicker: function() {...}`. But, throw just arrow func is there a some way to make it work in object, maybe with some non-classic `bind` method?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using es6 syntax then why not create a `Deck` class.

```
class Deck{
  constructor(){
    this.suits = ["hearts", "spades", "clubs", "diamonds"];
    this.cards = Array(52);
  }
  createCardPicker(){
    let pickedCard = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52);
    let pickedSuit = Math.floor(pickedCard / 13);
    return alert(this.suits[pickedSuit], pickedCard % 13)
  }
}
```

Then you can create an instance of the Deck and call the method inside:

```
let deck = new Deck();
deck.createCardPicker();
```